# React hooks, one for each child

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using the [`useDimensions`](https://github.com/Swizec/useDimensions) hook to measure my child components and update the parent component as a result (although this problem would also happen with any similar measurement hook). Thus, I want to `useDimensions` for each child component I have. However, this is a generic parent component that can accept any number of child components, so I *have* to loop over children and add a hook for each.

It currently looks a bit like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import useDimensions from "react-use-dimensions";

function Parent(props){
    const measurements = props.children.map(child => useDimensions());
    return props.children.map(
        (child, i) => React.cloneElement(child, {ref: measurements[i][0]})
    );
}
```

However, this breaks the [first rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level): **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.**

What is the best practise way to do this, without breaking the rules of React hooks?

Comment: I haven't yet gone to Hooks, but if possible: what about passing the hook down and call it in separation at each child?

Comment: @SultanH. I could render a new component that wraps each child, and calls the hook in there, and reports the dimensions back to the parent using a function. But that seems like a waste of time and the addition of lots of abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons for the rules of hooks are well explained in [Why Do React Hooks Rely on Call Order](https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/).

It would be easy if total dimensions are needed, without measuring each child individually:

```
function Parent({children}) {
  const [ref] = useDimensions()
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

For a more complicated scenario, structuring React code into multiple Components is a valid approach, neither "a waste of time" nor "addition of lots of abstraction", e.g.:

```
function Parent({children}) {
  const measurements = useRef(Array(children.length))

  const createSetRef = (i) => (ref) => {
    measurements[i] = ref
  }

  return children.map(
    (child, i) => <Child setRef={createSetRef(i)}>{child}</Child>
  )
}

function Child({children, setRef}) {
  const [ref] = useDimensions()

  useEffect(() => setRef(ref), [])

  if (React.isValidElement(children)) {
    return React.cloneElement(children, {ref})
  } else {
    console.log("TODO:", children)
    return children
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this actually *better* than using hooks in a loop in terms of performance or React behaviour, or will it just make React happier?

Comment: using hooks in a loop will not work (try to change the number of children between re-renders). unless you like debugging asynchronous mutable shared state with race conditions, think of the Rules of Hooks as rules of physics, not as ignorable suggestions (would you even ask "Is this actually _better_ than using antigravity???")

Comment: if using hooks in a loop was possible, then it would make sense to talk about performance (and I have no idea how it would end up, probably completely unnoticeable differences). until then, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: Using hooks in a loop *is* possible but absolutely not recommended. If you're absolutely certain that the number of elements in the loop will *never* change and the order of elements will *never* change then it likely won't break.... but it's still a bad idea. As suggested it's better to just wrap the items in their own function components.